# NPM is completely broken, cannot install due to phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 error: Cannot find module 'isarray'

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

I've been switching back and forth between two dev machines, and recently updated node on both versions, which has basically lobotomized my entire node project. After upgrading to v8 on my personal machine, it broke the binaries on my work machine which was still on 6, so after upgrading that one to 8, and pulling back on my personal machine, it is utterly broken.

I've tried deleting node modules, clearing the npm cache, reinstalling node modules, etc, nothing has worked at all, and it is all because of this stupid phantom dependency.

Edit: *most* of the time when I run `npm install`, the error is that it cannot find 'isarray' but the example here has a different dependency listed. It is so confusing, each time it fails for one of two reasons.

Error:

```
> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /Users/w/Turnout-V2/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

module.js:487
    throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'request-progress'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/w/Turnout-V2/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
npm WARN The package pug is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

More logs:

```
2739 warn The package pug is included as both a dev and production dependency.
2740 verbose stack Error: phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install: `node install.js`
2740 verbose stack Exit status 1
2740 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
2740 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
2740 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
2740 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
2740 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
2740 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
2740 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
2740 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
2741 verbose pkgid phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16
2742 verbose cwd /Users/w/Turnout-V2
2743 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
2744 verbose argv "/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node" "/Users/w/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
2745 verbose node v8.0.0
2746 verbose npm  v5.0.0
```

Comment: Why on earth are you syncing binaries in node_modules between machines!?!?

Comment: @fredstark Here's what I did. I started out on Node 6, installed my modules, then realized I wanted to use async/await, so upgraded to 8, and installed other modules. On my work machine, I needed to upgrade to 8 as well, and pull to get the new node modules and rebuild.